# Don't maximize an app's window which was previously minimized to dock when click app icon in dock?

Tags: window-manager

Is it possible to prevent a system from maximizing an app's window which was previously minimized to dock when I click the app icon in Dock or when I type app name in Spotlight/Alfred?

What I want to get: when I type app name or click app icon in Dock, it's last minimized window should not come to the front.

I just want to see the app (its status bar, for example), not its windows with old documents.

Comment: Is this a question specific to web browsers, or another specific app, or is this a general problem with all apps you work with?

Comment: @l008com It's a general problem, macOS brings a minimized window to front if you type app name for all apps. Guess that's the default behavior.

Comment: It is default behavior, and it's normally not a problem for me. It was an issue with web browsers, so I made an applescript that i put in place of Safari in my dock. When you click on it, it creates a new safari window, without un-minimizing windows, and without switching desktops. For that specific 1-app case, it's very handy. But it won't solve the problem overall.

Comment: Smart idea, glad I'm not the only one annoyed. Hope to find a generic solution though.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/266165/stop-minimized-windows-from-opening-when-application-gets-focus-in-os-x) Superuser.SE question answers your question.

Comment: @Christian so the only way to create applescripts for each app I use?

Comment: Or use the application switcher to select the app first. The maximizing of a window appears to be the unalterable system default.